# Why does the cstdlib strncpy crash whilst copying a char array to a character pointer

Tags: c, string

This is my code:

```
char* ToC(char src[STRING_SIZE], char* dest)
{
     if ( src[0] == 0 )
        dest = NULL;
     else
          strncpy(dest, &src[0], size_t(strlen(src)));
}
```

---

How it gets called :

```
typedef struct sdata
{
     char* point_one;

}tsdata

tsdata sdata;

char name[STRING_SIZE] = "point_data";

ToC(name, sdata.point_one);
```

strncpy always crashes.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You have probably not made `dest` point to a large enough block of memory.

Comment: Post the function which calls this function. This info is not enough

Comment: Also, please remove the c++ tag while you are at updating...

Comment: You might not be allocating memory properly to `char *dest`.
Well, can you please elaborate your question a little more?

Comment: Why are you setting `dest = NULL`? It doesn't do anything since `dest` is local in scope to the `ToC` function. If the caller counts on this, then it will be a bug. Also, note that in the documentation for `strncpy`: *Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will  not  be  null-terminated.* So watch for that.

Comment: @MadHatter: please do not cause more edits than needed... it will make it get community wiki easier...

Comment: @lurker working with a strange API that *asks* me to make it NULL that way.

Comment: `sdata.point_one` doesn't have a valid memory address assigned to it! You need to allocate memory (using `malloc`) and assign to `sdata.point_one`.

Comment: @Wildling it still does nothing, whether the API asks for it or not.

Comment: @lurker yes, I am trying to make it point to the character array in the function call to `ToC`

Comment: Also, the third argument to `strncpy` should be the amount of space available at `dest` (not the source length). `strncpy` is a poor choice of function anyway; either use `strcpy` after checking lengths, or `snprintf`.

Comment: @lurker, thanks, I must return dest..

Comment: The function has no `return` statement, so it currently returns nothing. You would need a `return dest;`. The caller, however, doesn't look at the return value, so that won't do much.

Comment: @lurker can you explain why modifying a pointer inside the function does not persist the change made to the pointer once the function call is over ? This is pass by pointer right ? Shouldn't the `NULL` added to dest or the data added to it using the `strncpy` function remain steady as I have modified the contents of the memory location that dest points to ?

Comment: In `char *dest`, the `dest` is a variable *local* to the scope of the function that contains a pointer. You are explicitly passing a pointer. Assigning `dest = NULL` sets the *local* pointer to NULL. Setting `*dest = NULL` would set what `dest` points to to NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
typedef struct sdata
{
     char* point_one;

}tsdata

tsdata sdata;

char name[STRING_SIZE] = "point_data";

ToC(name, sdata.point_one);
```

calls `Toc` with second argument an uninitialized pointer, which is passed by value.

That *indeterminate value* is used as the destination pointer.

→ crash, or more generally Undefined Behavior.

---

General comments.

---

In this function declaration,

```
void ToC(char src[STRING_SIZE], char* dest)
```

- the `STRING_SIZE` is ignored by the compiler and is not available to following code.

---

And in this code snippet:

```
 if ( src[0] == 0 )
    dest = NULL;
```

- the assignment changes the value of a local variable (a function argument), which is not used further in the function.

---

Also, for the updated question where the function declaration was changed to

```
char* ToC(char src[STRING_SIZE], char* dest)
```

- the function lacks a `return` statement, so any use of the function result is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: @Wildling: one way is to allocate some space and make `point_one` point at that space. but better, in C++ switch over to using `std::string`, which takes care of memory management for you. that's what it's for. i notice that the C++ tag has been removed from the question. in C you don't have anything like `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tsdata sdata;

char name[STRING_SIZE] = "point_data";

ToC(name, sdata.point_one);
```

You have not allocated any space to `sdata.point_one` pointer.

`tsdata sdata` statically allocates memory equal to `sizeof(sdata)` which actually is just the size of pointer `point_one`.

You should allocate memory to `point_one` as `sdata.point_one = malloc(sizeof(name));` or some other size.

Comment: I must do a `malloc` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution.  It allocates a block of memory suitable to store a copy of 'src', and copies 'src' to that memory, and set's the caller supplied pointer to the allocated memory. (It returns a non-zero value to indicate failure):

```
#include <string.h>        // strdup();
#include <errno.h>         // ENOMEM

int ToC(
      char  *I__src, 
      char **_O_dest
      )
   {
   int rCode=0;
   char *dest = NULL;

   if(0 == I__src[0])
      *_O_dest = NULL;
   else
      {
      *_O_dest=strdup(I__src);
      if(NULL == *_O_dest)
         rCode = ENOMEM;
      }

   return(rCode);
   }
```

The above function would be called something like this:

```
{
...
int   rCode = 0;
char *anyLengthString = "The brother of Jared";
char *copy = NULL;

...

rCode=ToC(anyLengthString, &copy);
if(rCode)
   {
   fprintf(stderr, "ToC() reports error: %d\n", rCode);
   ...
   }

...

if(copy)
   free(copy);

...
}
```